# Empty IPv6 address causes DNS error on Macs running Apache Server

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, mac-osx, ipv6, ipv4

For a site I manage, http://archstl.org/, the DNS entry returns an empty (::) IPv6 address when I run `$ host archstl.org` in the Terminal.

I think the errant IPv6 entry may be the cause of my problem: when a Mac user running Apache Web Server (any flavor) tries to visit archstl.org, they get localhost instead (the Mac seems to pick up archstl.org's IPv6 address rather than the IPv4 address, 174.37.22.142).

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I'm not even sure how the IPv6 address is being output for our DNS entry; I don't have any other domain names that return an IPv6 address.

See here for more info on my own troubleshooting: http://archstldev.com/node/74

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::` is [the all-zeroes address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Special_addresses), similar to 0.0.0.0 in IPv4. This isn't even localhost (::1) — it's guaranteed to make your site unreachable over IPv6. If your web server has IPv6 connectivity, point the AAAA record for archstl.org at its IPv6 address. If it doesn't remove the AAAA record entirely.

Comment: Thanks! I will contact our IT department to see if they can change the AAAA record. I don't actually have the control over this domain name... I'll post back here with the results.

Comment: I have talked to IT, and they said they put in the AAAA record to fix a different issue with IPv6 timeouts they were having. They are looking into possible solutions, and I've filed a support ticket with our hosting provider to see if they have any solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - after they removed the AAAA record, everything works great!